# T-SQL : Using ROW_NUMBER() to paginate FOR XML - child nodes not being returned

Tags: t-sql, pagination, row-number, for-xml

I'm running the following query

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TransactionValues].[ID]) AS idx,
    [Transactions].[ID] AS [id],
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] AS [encryptedAccountID],
    [Transactions].[Uploaded] AS [uploaded],
    [Transactions].[Visible] AS [visible],
    [Fields].[ID] AS [fieldId],
    [Fields].[FriendlyName] AS [friendlyName],
    [Fields].[OfficialName] AS [officialName],
    [Fields].[Order] AS [order],
    [Fields].[Visible] AS [valueVisible],
    [TransactionValues].[ID] AS [valueId],
    [TransactionValues].[FieldID] AS [valueFieldId],
    [TransactionValues].[FriendlyValue] AS [friendlyValue],
    [TransactionValues].[OfficialValue] AS [officialValue],
    [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] AS [transactionId]
FROM
    [Transactions]
    INNER JOIN [TransactionValues]
    ON [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] = [Transactions].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [Fields]
    ON [TransactionValues].[FieldID] = [Fields].[ID]
WHERE
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] = @encryptedAccountID
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
```

Which returns XML in the following format (I've omitted the returned attribute values - these aren't pertinent):

```
<root>
    <Transactions idx="" id="" encryptedAccountID="" uploaded="" visible="">
        <Fields id="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" visible="">
            <TransactionValues valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
        </Fields>
        <Fields id="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" visible="">
            <TransactionValues valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
        </Fields>
    </Transactions>
    <Transactions idx="" id="" encryptedAccountID="" uploaded="" visible="">
        <Fields id="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" visible="">
            <TransactionValues valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
        </Fields>
        <Fields id="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" visible="">
            <TransactionValues valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
        </Fields>
    </Transactions>
</root>
```

So far so good.

Now, I want to paginate the results. Part of this requires that the above query is run as a sub-query. So I now have the following query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TransactionValues].[ID]) AS idx,
        [Transactions].[ID] AS [id],
        [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] AS [encryptedAccountID],
        [Transactions].[Uploaded] AS [uploaded],
        [Transactions].[Visible] AS [visible],
        [Fields].[ID] AS [fieldId],
        [Fields].[FriendlyName] AS [friendlyName],
        [Fields].[OfficialName] AS [officialName],
        [Fields].[Order] AS [order],
        [Fields].[Visible] AS [valueVisible],
        [TransactionValues].[ID] AS [valueId],
        [TransactionValues].[FieldID] AS [valueFieldId],
        [TransactionValues].[FriendlyValue] AS [friendlyValue],
        [TransactionValues].[OfficialValue] AS [officialValue],
        [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] AS [transactionId]
    FROM
        [Transactions]
        INNER JOIN [TransactionValues]
        ON [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] = [Transactions].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [Fields]
        ON [TransactionValues].[FieldID] = .[Fields].[ID]
    WHERE
        [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] = @encryptedAccountID
) AS [TransactionInfo]
WHERE
    idx > 5
AND
    idx <= 20
ORDER BY
    [id], [order] ASC
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
```

However, this returns the following XML

```
<root>
    <TransactionInfo idx="" id="" encryptedAccountID="" uploaded="" visible="" fieldId="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" valueVisible="" valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
    <TransactionInfo idx="" id="" encryptedAccountID="" uploaded="" visible="" fieldId="" friendlyName="" officialName="" order="" valueVisible="" valueId="" valueFieldId="" friendlyValue="" officialValue="" transactionId="" />
</root>
```

You can see that the introduction of the sub-query has caused the FOR XML clause to no longer nest the child results... but I don't understand why.

Can anyone tell me how I can implement pagination via ROW_NUMBER(), and stil have the results formatted like the first block of XML above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isnt pretty, but how about this:

```
SELECT
    [Transactions].[ID] AS [id],
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] AS [encryptedAccountID],
    [Transactions].[Uploaded] AS [uploaded],
    [Transactions].[Visible] AS [visible],
    [Fields].[ID] AS [fieldId],
    [Fields].[FriendlyName] AS [friendlyName],
    [Fields].[OfficialName] AS [officialName],
    [Fields].[Order] AS [order],
    [Fields].[Visible] AS [valueVisible],
    [TransactionValues].[ID] AS [valueId],
    [TransactionValues].[FieldID] AS [valueFieldId],
    [TransactionValues].[FriendlyValue] AS [friendlyValue],
    [TransactionValues].[OfficialValue] AS [officialValue],
    [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] AS [transactionId],
    [TransactionValues].idx
FROM
    [Transactions]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TransactionValues].[ID]) AS idx
        FROM [TransactionValues]
    ) AS [TransactionValues]
        ON [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] = [Transactions].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [Fields]
        ON [TransactionValues].[FieldID] = .[Fields].[ID]
WHERE
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] = @encryptedAccountID
    AND [TransactionValues].idx BETWEEN 5 AND 20
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
```

Comment: This produces the error:
"Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: That's _pretty much_ it, @Justin. Your query was returning the wrong order of nesting (the TransactionValue was outermost, inside which was Field and inside that was Transaction). It took me a few minutes to switch this around. The new sub-query you added wouldn't allow me to order the Transactions by TransactionValue.ID, so I've added a new auto-assigned int to Transaction (which is now part of a combmined primary key). So in summary, with a little tweaking I got there. For posterity, should I post the complete query solution below?

Comment: @awj I updated my answer to have idx at the bottom, which would nest appropriately now. However, it never hurts to update with what you did end up using. If this answer helped, upvotes are always appreciated, and if it pushed you in the right direction for your own answer, then accepts are especially appreciated. Either way, always glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Justin Pihoney, here's my solution:

```
SELECT
    [Transactions].[AssignedID],
    [Transactions].[idx],
    [Transactions].[ID] AS [id],
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] AS [encryptedAccountID],
    [Transactions].[Uploaded] AS [uploaded],
    [Transactions].[Visible] AS [visible],
    [Fields].[ID] AS [id],
    [Fields].[FriendlyName] AS [friendlyName],
    [Fields].[OfficialName] AS [officialName],
    [Fields].[Order] AS [order],
    [Fields].[Visible] AS [visible],
    [TransactionValues].[ID] AS [id],
    [TransactionValues].[FieldID] AS [fieldId],
    [TransactionValues].[FriendlyValue] AS [friendlyValue],
    [TransactionValues].[OfficialValue] AS [officialValue],
    [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] AS [transactionId]
FROM
    [TransactionValues]
    INNER JOIN [Fields]
    ON [TransactionValues].[FieldID] = .[Fields].[ID]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Transactions].[AssignedID]) AS [idx]
        FROM [Transactions]
    ) AS [Transactions]
    ON [TransactionValues].[TransactionID] = [Transactions].[ID]
WHERE
    [Transactions].[EncryptedAccountID] = @EncryptedAccountID
AND
    [Transactions].[idx] BETWEEN 5 AND 20
ORDER BY
    [Transactions].[AssignedID]
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('root')
```

Also, just for completeness, the "BETWEEN 5 AND 20" *will* be replaced by parameters.